# How to build a ColorFunction that can take a non-numeric value? Blend returns an error

Tags: function-construction, color

I'm trying to use an external package, defined [here](http://www.mathematicaguidebooks.org/V6/downloads/RiemannSurfacePlot3D.m). This package has a private function called `makeColorFunction` that essentially works by taking an input color function, written in terms of an undefined variable, and makes a pure function out of it by way of a replacement rule inside a call to `Evaluate`.  Here is an example with `Hue[Re[z]]` given as the argument:

```
makeColorFunction[rhs_, z_] := 
          Function[Evaluate[(rhs  /. {Re[z] -> #1})]]

makeColorFunction[Hue[Re[z]], z]
(* Hue[#1] & *)
```

`makeColorFunction` is already written in the package that I am using, so I need to be able to just work with it, rather than change it.

I want to be able to feed this my own color functions that I usually make by using `Blend`, and it seems to work but gives an error:

```
colors = {#, 1 - #, #} & /@ Range[0, 1, .33];
myColorFunction = (Blend[RGBColor @@@ colors, #] &)
makeColorFunction[myColorFunction[Re@z], z]
```

> During evaluation of Blend::argl: Re[z] should be a real number or a
>   list of non-negative numbers, which has the same length as {,,,}. >>
>
> During evaluation of Blend::argl: #1 should be a real number or a list of non-negative numbers, which has the same length as {,,,}. >>

```
(* Blend[{RGBColor[0., 1., 0.], RGBColor[
   0.33, 0.6699999999999999, 0.33], RGBColor[
   0.66, 0.33999999999999997`, 0.66], RGBColor[
   0.99, 0.010000000000000009`, 0.99]}, #1] & *)
```

So it does work in that it returns the expected pure function, but it gives an error.  Since I would rather not use `Quiet`, I want another way to build up this color function.

The issue is that these two do not return an error,

```
Hue[x]
ColorData["ThermometerColors"][x]
```

while this does:

```
Blend[RGBColor @@@ colors, x]
```

In the end, I guess I would like to be able to make a `ColorFunction` that behaves in every way just like the built-in functions, but I don't know what attribute they possess that I need to add to my own.

I suppose this boils down to the question of why `Hue` can take symbolic arguments, but `Blend` cannot?  `Blend[{Red, Blue}, x]` gives the error, but `Hue[x]` doesn't.

Comment: This should work slightly better than Trott's version: `SetAttributes[makeColorFunction, HoldAll]; makeColorFunction[rhs_, {z_, w_}] := Apply[Function, Hold[rhs] /. {Re[z] -> #1, Im[z] -> #2, Re[w] -> #3, Im[w] -> #4, Abs[z] -> Sqrt[#1^2 + #2^2], Abs[w] -> Sqrt[#3^2 + #4^2], Arg[z] -> ArcTan[#1, #2], Arg[z] -> ArcTan[#3, #4]}]`. (I have taken the opportunity to restore the square roots where they ought to be.)

Comment: @J.M. But then I have to modify an in-package function.  I was hoping there was some attribute I could set on `myColorFunction` that would make it behave like all the built-in color functions

Comment: I did try adding `SetAttributes[makeColorFunction, HoldAll]` to Trott's version, but no dice. Also, `Blend[]` evaluates instantly, so `Blend[{Red, Blue}, z]` quickly throws an error, as opposed to the `*Color[]` functions that are inert for nonnumeric arguments.

Comment: The first code block doesn't evaluate to the shown output.

Comment: @Karsten, I confess that I dug up the definition from Trott's package instead of using Jason's simplified version.

Comment: @Karsten7. You are right, I must have messed it up in my edit

Comment: maybe `Inactive/Activate` to prevent `Blend` from evaluating: `myColorFunction = (Inactive[Blend][RGBColor @@@ colors, #] &)
Plot[Sin[x], {x, 0, Pi}, ColorFunction ->Activate[  makeColorFunction[myColorFunction[Re@z], z]]]`, or `Activate@Plot[Sin[x], {x, 0, Pi}, ColorFunction ->  makeColorFunction[myColorFunction[Re@z], z]]`?

Comment: Is there any reason why `Blend` should behave this way?  It almost seems it should be reported as a bug.

Comment: @george2079 - I can't even get the very first lines in this post to work any more: http://i.stack.imgur.com/UAGHH.png, oddly enough.  Looking at this now, the gist is that `Blend` won't take a non-numeric value, right?  In that `Blend[{Red, Blue}, x]` gives the same error.  I don't see why it can't take symbolic values, but it doesn't really say in the docs that it can....

Comment: I'd argue the docs should explicitly say numeric arguments only.  The `With` construct I used here http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/127329/2079 addresses part of the issue, but still doesn't work for your problem.