# Colormaps for linear visual perception AND grayscale printing

Tags: color, perception

There are already good approaches for "better than standard" colormaps in Mathematica, which are optimized for a more linear perception between the visible colors and their underlying values, here in StackExchange: [Is there an easy way to use Matteo Niccoli's perceptual color maps for 2D plots in Mathematica?](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/64513)

Nevertheless, those considerations can go even further into thinking of colormaps that also include linear perception for persons impaired by deuteranopia or protanopia. Also the grayscale-printing can be optimized.

Have a look at [this page](https://bids.github.io/colormap/).

Example:
[image: plots with viridis colormap]

### Question:

Far down in the article, there are some hints to generate those maps using Python. How can those maps be generated and used in Mathematica? I am particularly interested in "Option D (Viridis)".

### What I have tried/found out so far:

On the article's website, I found [a Python script](https://github.com/BIDS/colormap/blob/master/option_d.py) including a variable `cm_data`, which contains apparently RGB values (scaled from 0.0 to 1.0) in a structure like: `[[R1,G1,B1],...,[Rn,Bn,Gn]]`. I'm not familiar with parsing such a string into a useful `List` in Mathematica.

Comment: I added some information about this

Comment: You can think of some ways to programmatically parse `cm_data`, but why not just open a text editor or even MA for that matter and replace `[` with `{` and so on. You will get a `List`which is perfectly valid MA construction.

Comment: Well, I'm kind of embarrassed by the disarming simplicity of your idea. It is completely acceptable, and I'm going to do it like this.

Comment: FYI: I don't know about others, but the answer I provided on [the question](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/64513) you linked to reduces to grayscale appropriately. I believe it should also work for various types of colorblindness since the data is actually coded in the intensity, though using different parameters for differentiation between plots would require more consideration.

Comment: Possible Duplicate: http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/84877/5

Comment: Related: [Create colour with given lightness value](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/8746/create-colour-with-given-lightness-value)

Answer (score 20, accepted):

Didn't see george's answer when I worked this out, but I'll go ahead and post since it has all the maps from that page.  The `StringReplace` here is pretty embarrassing, but I was going for quick and dirty

```
ClearAll@MPLColorMap
Set[
 Evaluate[
  MPLColorMap /@
   {"Magma", "Inferno", "Plasma", "Viridis", 
    "EricsRdBuGnYl", "EricsRdBuGnYl2", "EricsPuBuGnYl", "FakeParula", 
    "JoesBluGrnPnk2"}
  ],
 Function[url,
   ReadList[url, "String"][[
        Span[#1, #2 - 1] & @@ (Flatten@Position[
            StringPosition[test, "cm_data", IgnoreCase -> True],
            Except@{}, 1, Heads -> False])]] //
      StringReplace[
       {"[[" -> "{", "]]" -> "}", "]," -> "}", "[" -> "{", "]" -> "}",
         "cm_data = " -> "", "e" -> "*^"}
       ] // Map@RGBColor@*ToExpression // 
    Function[x, Blend[#, x]] &] /@ {
"https://raw.githubusercontent.com/BIDS/colormap/master/option_a.py",
"https://raw.githubusercontent.com/BIDS/colormap/master/option_b.py",
"https://raw.githubusercontent.com/BIDS/colormap/master/option_c.py",
"https://raw.githubusercontent.com/BIDS/colormap/master/option_d.py",
"https://github.com/BIDS/colormap/raw/master/erics-RdBuGnYl_r.py",
"https://github.com/BIDS/colormap/raw/master/erics-RdBuGnYl_r_v2.py",
"https://github.com/BIDS/colormap/raw/master/erics_PuBuGnYl_r.py",
"https://github.com/BIDS/colormap/raw/master/fake_parula.py",
"https://github.com/BIDS/colormap/raw/master/joes-blu_grn_pnk2.py"}
]
```

You can skip that code above and just import the data using

```
ClearAll[MPLColorMap]
<< "http://pastebin.com/raw/pFsb4ZBS";
```

Which defines all the color maps as downvalues of `MPLColorMap`.  You can now access the color maps like

```
MPLColorMap["Magma"][.8]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

and use them via

```
DensityPlot[Sin[x - y], {x, -3, 3}, {y, -3, 3}, 
 ColorFunction -> MPLColorMap["Viridis"]]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

Here are all the new color maps shown using the `showcolorfunction` defined [here](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/101625/9490),

```
showcolorfunction[MPLColorMap[#]] & /@ {"Magma", "Inferno", "Plasma", 
  "Viridis", "EricsRdBuGnYl", "EricsRdBuGnYl2", "EricsPuBuGnYl", 
  "FakeParula", "JoesBluGrnPnk2"}
```

[image]

Comment: This is great! Thanks for the efforts! I'm still going to accept @george2079 's answer, as it is a more compact form. Nevertheless I appreciate your work  very much :)

Comment: Glad to be of help!

Comment: Your last edit makes the use of your variant very easy. Clear Like!

Comment: Might be worth updating this, as the code as posted now throws errors because of changes in formatting I'm assuming. Might also be worth putting this kind of thing in the Data Repository?

Comment: @JasonB. I've made this into an official WFR item: https://resources.wolframcloud.com/FunctionRepository/resources/AddMatplotlibColors/ ! Now it's very easy to use those colors.

Answer (score 9):

Thanks to @yarchik, I made it work for Mathematica, by simply replacing `[` and `]` with `{` and `}` using a text editor:

```
viridis=Module[{colorlist},
colorlist={{0.26700401,0.00487433,0.32941519},{0.26851048,0.00960483,0.33542652},{0.26994384,0.01462494,0.34137895},{0.27130489,0.01994186,0.34726862},{0.27259384,0.02556309,0.35309303},{0.27380934,0.03149748,0.35885256},{0.27495242,0.03775181,0.36454323},{0.27602238,0.04416723,0.37016418},{0.2770184,0.05034437,0.37571452},{0.27794143,0.05632444,0.38119074},{0.27879067,0.06214536,0.38659204},{0.2795655,0.06783587,0.39191723},{0.28026658,0.07341724,0.39716349},{0.28089358,0.07890703,0.40232944},{0.28144581,0.0843197,0.40741404},{0.28192358,0.08966622,0.41241521},{0.28232739,0.09495545,0.41733086},{0.28265633,0.10019576,0.42216032},{0.28291049,0.10539345,0.42690202},{0.28309095,0.11055307,0.43155375},{0.28319704,0.11567966,0.43611482},{0.28322882,0.12077701,0.44058404},{0.28318684,0.12584799,0.44496},{0.283072,0.13089477,0.44924127},{0.28288389,0.13592005,0.45342734},{0.28262297,0.14092556,0.45751726},{0.28229037,0.14591233,0.46150995},{0.28188676,0.15088147,0.46540474},{0.28141228,0.15583425,0.46920128},{0.28086773,0.16077132,0.47289909},{0.28025468,0.16569272,0.47649762},{0.27957399,0.17059884,0.47999675},{0.27882618,0.1754902,0.48339654},{0.27801236,0.18036684,0.48669702},{0.27713437,0.18522836,0.48989831},{0.27619376,0.19007447,0.49300074},{0.27519116,0.1949054,0.49600488},{0.27412802,0.19972086,0.49891131},{0.27300596,0.20452049,0.50172076},{0.27182812,0.20930306,0.50443413},{0.27059473,0.21406899,0.50705243},{0.26930756,0.21881782,0.50957678},{0.26796846,0.22354911,0.5120084},{0.26657984,0.2282621,0.5143487},{0.2651445,0.23295593,0.5165993},{0.2636632,0.23763078,0.51876163},{0.26213801,0.24228619,0.52083736},{0.26057103,0.2469217,0.52282822},{0.25896451,0.25153685,0.52473609},{0.25732244,0.2561304,0.52656332},{0.25564519,0.26070284,0.52831152},{0.25393498,0.26525384,0.52998273},{0.25219404,0.26978306,0.53157905},{0.25042462,0.27429024,0.53310261},{0.24862899,0.27877509,0.53455561},{0.2468114,0.28323662,0.53594093},{0.24497208,0.28767547,0.53726018},{0.24311324,0.29209154,0.53851561},{0.24123708,0.29648471,0.53970946},{0.23934575,0.30085494,0.54084398},{0.23744138,0.30520222,0.5419214},{0.23552606,0.30952657,0.54294396},{0.23360277,0.31382773,0.54391424},{0.2316735,0.3181058,0.54483444},{0.22973926,0.32236127,0.54570633},{0.22780192,0.32659432,0.546532},{0.2258633,0.33080515,0.54731353},{0.22392515,0.334994,0.54805291},{0.22198915,0.33916114,0.54875211},{0.22005691,0.34330688,0.54941304},{0.21812995,0.34743154,0.55003755},{0.21620971,0.35153548,0.55062743},{0.21429757,0.35561907,0.5511844},{0.21239477,0.35968273,0.55171011},{0.2105031,0.36372671,0.55220646},{0.20862342,0.36775151,0.55267486},{0.20675628,0.37175775,0.55311653},{0.20490257,0.37574589,0.55353282},{0.20306309,0.37971644,0.55392505},{0.20123854,0.38366989,0.55429441},{0.1994295,0.38760678,0.55464205},{0.1976365,0.39152762,0.55496905},{0.19585993,0.39543297,0.55527637},{0.19410009,0.39932336,0.55556494},{0.19235719,0.40319934,0.55583559},{0.19063135,0.40706148,0.55608907},{0.18892259,0.41091033,0.55632606},{0.18723083,0.41474645,0.55654717},{0.18555593,0.4185704,0.55675292},{0.18389763,0.42238275,0.55694377},{0.18225561,0.42618405,0.5571201},{0.18062949,0.42997486,0.55728221},{0.17901879,0.43375572,0.55743035},{0.17742298,0.4375272,0.55756466},{0.17584148,0.44128981,0.55768526},{0.17427363,0.4450441,0.55779216},{0.17271876,0.4487906,0.55788532},{0.17117615,0.4525298,0.55796464},{0.16964573,0.45626209,0.55803034},{0.16812641,0.45998802,0.55808199},{0.1666171,0.46370813,0.55811913},{0.16511703,0.4674229,0.55814141},{0.16362543,0.47113278,0.55814842},{0.16214155,0.47483821,0.55813967},{0.16066467,0.47853961,0.55811466},{0.15919413,0.4822374,0.5580728},{0.15772933,0.48593197,0.55801347},{0.15626973,0.4896237,0.557936},{0.15481488,0.49331293,0.55783967},{0.15336445,0.49700003,0.55772371},{0.1519182,0.50068529,0.55758733},{0.15047605,0.50436904,0.55742968},{0.14903918,0.50805136,0.5572505},{0.14760731,0.51173263,0.55704861},{0.14618026,0.51541316,0.55682271},{0.14475863,0.51909319,0.55657181},{0.14334327,0.52277292,0.55629491},{0.14193527,0.52645254,0.55599097},{0.14053599,0.53013219,0.55565893},{0.13914708,0.53381201,0.55529773},{0.13777048,0.53749213,0.55490625},{0.1364085,0.54117264,0.55448339},{0.13506561,0.54485335,0.55402906},{0.13374299,0.54853458,0.55354108},{0.13244401,0.55221637,0.55301828},{0.13117249,0.55589872,0.55245948},{0.1299327,0.55958162,0.55186354},{0.12872938,0.56326503,0.55122927},{0.12756771,0.56694891,0.55055551},{0.12645338,0.57063316,0.5498411},{0.12539383,0.57431754,0.54908564},{0.12439474,0.57800205,0.5482874},{0.12346281,0.58168661,0.54744498},{0.12260562,0.58537105,0.54655722},{0.12183122,0.58905521,0.54562298},{0.12114807,0.59273889,0.54464114},{0.12056501,0.59642187,0.54361058},{0.12009154,0.60010387,0.54253043},{0.11973756,0.60378459,0.54139999},{0.11951163,0.60746388,0.54021751},{0.11942341,0.61114146,0.53898192},{0.11948255,0.61481702,0.53769219},{0.11969858,0.61849025,0.53634733},{0.12008079,0.62216081,0.53494633},{0.12063824,0.62582833,0.53348834},{0.12137972,0.62949242,0.53197275},{0.12231244,0.63315277,0.53039808},{0.12344358,0.63680899,0.52876343},{0.12477953,0.64046069,0.52706792},{0.12632581,0.64410744,0.52531069},{0.12808703,0.64774881,0.52349092},{0.13006688,0.65138436,0.52160791},{0.13226797,0.65501363,0.51966086},{0.13469183,0.65863619,0.5176488},{0.13733921,0.66225157,0.51557101},{0.14020991,0.66585927,0.5134268},{0.14330291,0.66945881,0.51121549},{0.1466164,0.67304968,0.50893644},{0.15014782,0.67663139,0.5065889},{0.15389405,0.68020343,0.50417217},{0.15785146,0.68376525,0.50168574},{0.16201598,0.68731632,0.49912906},{0.1663832,0.69085611,0.49650163},{0.1709484,0.69438405,0.49380294},{0.17570671,0.6978996,0.49103252},{0.18065314,0.70140222,0.48818938},{0.18578266,0.70489133,0.48527326},{0.19109018,0.70836635,0.48228395},{0.19657063,0.71182668,0.47922108},{0.20221902,0.71527175,0.47608431},{0.20803045,0.71870095,0.4728733},{0.21400015,0.72211371,0.46958774},{0.22012381,0.72550945,0.46622638},{0.2263969,0.72888753,0.46278934},{0.23281498,0.73224735,0.45927675},{0.2393739,0.73558828,0.45568838},{0.24606968,0.73890972,0.45202405},{0.25289851,0.74221104,0.44828355},{0.25985676,0.74549162,0.44446673},{0.26694127,0.74875084,0.44057284},{0.27414922,0.75198807,0.4366009},{0.28147681,0.75520266,0.43255207},{0.28892102,0.75839399,0.42842626},{0.29647899,0.76156142,0.42422341},{0.30414796,0.76470433,0.41994346},{0.31192534,0.76782207,0.41558638},{0.3198086,0.77091403,0.41115215},{0.3277958,0.77397953,0.40664011},{0.33588539,0.7770179,0.40204917},{0.34407411,0.78002855,0.39738103},{0.35235985,0.78301086,0.39263579},{0.36074053,0.78596419,0.38781353},{0.3692142,0.78888793,0.38291438},{0.37777892,0.79178146,0.3779385},{0.38643282,0.79464415,0.37288606},{0.39517408,0.79747541,0.36775726},{0.40400101,0.80027461,0.36255223},{0.4129135,0.80304099,0.35726893},{0.42190813,0.80577412,0.35191009},{0.43098317,0.80847343,0.34647607},{0.44013691,0.81113836,0.3409673},{0.44936763,0.81376835,0.33538426},{0.45867362,0.81636288,0.32972749},{0.46805314,0.81892143,0.32399761},{0.47750446,0.82144351,0.31819529},{0.4870258,0.82392862,0.31232133},{0.49661536,0.82637633,0.30637661},{0.5062713,0.82878621,0.30036211},{0.51599182,0.83115784,0.29427888},{0.52577622,0.83349064,0.2881265},{0.5356211,0.83578452,0.28190832},{0.5455244,0.83803918,0.27562602},{0.55548397,0.84025437,0.26928147},{0.5654976,0.8424299,0.26287683},{0.57556297,0.84456561,0.25641457},{0.58567772,0.84666139,0.24989748},{0.59583934,0.84871722,0.24332878},{0.60604528,0.8507331,0.23671214},{0.61629283,0.85270912,0.23005179},{0.62657923,0.85464543,0.22335258},{0.63690157,0.85654226,0.21662012},{0.64725685,0.85839991,0.20986086},{0.65764197,0.86021878,0.20308229},{0.66805369,0.86199932,0.19629307},{0.67848868,0.86374211,0.18950326},{0.68894351,0.86544779,0.18272455},{0.69941463,0.86711711,0.17597055},{0.70989842,0.86875092,0.16925712},{0.72039115,0.87035015,0.16260273},{0.73088902,0.87191584,0.15602894},{0.74138803,0.87344918,0.14956101},{0.75188414,0.87495143,0.14322828},{0.76237342,0.87642392,0.13706449},{0.77285183,0.87786808,0.13110864},{0.78331535,0.87928545,0.12540538},{0.79375994,0.88067763,0.12000532},{0.80418159,0.88204632,0.11496505},{0.81457634,0.88339329,0.11034678},{0.82494028,0.88472036,0.10621724},{0.83526959,0.88602943,0.1026459},{0.84556056,0.88732243,0.09970219},{0.8558096,0.88860134,0.09745186},{0.86601325,0.88986815,0.09595277},{0.87616824,0.89112487,0.09525046},{0.88627146,0.89237353,0.09537439},{0.89632002,0.89361614,0.09633538},{0.90631121,0.89485467,0.09812496},{0.91624212,0.89609127,0.1007168},{0.92610579,0.89732977,0.10407067},{0.93590444,0.8985704,0.10813094},{0.94563626,0.899815,0.11283773},{0.95529972,0.90106534,0.11812832},{0.96489353,0.90232311,0.12394051},{0.97441665,0.90358991,0.13021494},{0.98386829,0.90486726,0.13689671},{0.99324789,0.90615657,0.1439362}};
Evaluate[Blend[RGBColor @@@ colorlist, #] &]
];
BarLegend[{viridis, {0, 1}}]
```

[image: Viridis Colormap in Mathematica]

### Edit:

Another Example to visualize the grayscale-improvement ("Rainbow" vs. viridis):

```
mPlots = ContourPlot[Cos[x] Sin[y], {x, -10, 10}, {y, -10, 10}, PlotRange -> All, ColorFunction -> #, PlotPoints -> 75, ImageSize -> Medium] & /@
    {"Rainbow", viridis}
mPlots /. x: _RGBColor | _Hue | _CMYKColor :> ColorConvert[x, "Grayscale"]
```

[image]

Answer (score 7):

we should not need to manually fix the format.. cut-paste from https://github.com/BIDS/colormap/blob/master/option_b.py

```
pyarray = " [[  1.46159096e-03,   4.66127766e-04,   1.38655200e-02],
   [  2.26726368e-03,   1.26992553e-03,   1.85703520e-02],
   [  3.29899092e-03,   2.24934863e-03,   2.42390508e-02],
   [  4.54690615e-03,   3.39180156e-03,   3.09092475e-02],
   [  6.00552565e-03,   4.69194561e-03,   3.85578980e-02],
   [  7.67578856e-03,   6.13611626e-03,   4.68360336e-02],
   [  9.56051094e-03,   7.71344131e-03,   5.51430756e-02],
   [  1.16634769e-02,   9.41675403e-03,   6.34598080e-02],
   [  1.39950388e-02,   1.12247138e-02,   7.18616890e-02],
   [  1.65605595e-02,   1.31362262e-02,   8.02817951e-02],
   [  1.93732295e-02,   1.51325789e-02,   8.87668094e-02],
   [  2.24468865e-02,   1.71991484e-02,   9.73274383e-02],
   [  2.57927373e-02,   1.93306298e-02,   1.05929835e-01],
   [  2.94324251e-02,   2.15030771e-02,   1.14621328e-01],
   [  3.33852235e-02,   2.37024271e-02,   1.23397286e-01],
   [  3.76684211e-02,   2.59207864e-02,   1.32232108e-01],
   [  4.22525554e-02,   2.81385015e-02,   1.41140519e-01],
   [  4.69146287e-02,   3.03236129e-02,   1.50163867e-01],
   [  5.16437624e-02,   3.24736172e-02,   1.59254277e-01],
   [  5.64491009e-02,   3.45691867e-02,   1.68413539e-01],
   [  6.13397200e-02,   3.65900213e-02,   1.77642172e-01],
   [  6.63312620e-02,   3.85036268e-02,   1.86961588e-01],
   [  7.14289181e-02,   4.02939095e-02,   1.96353558e-01],
   [  7.66367560e-02,   4.19053329e-02,   2.05798788e-01],
   [  8.19620773e-02,   4.33278666e-02,   2.15289113e-01],
   [  8.74113897e-02,   4.45561662e-02,   2.24813479e-01],
   [  9.29901526e-02,   4.55829503e-02,   2.34357604e-01],
   [  9.87024972e-02,   4.64018731e-02,   2.43903700e-01],
   [  1.04550936e-01,   4.70080541e-02,   2.53430300e-01],
   [  1.10536084e-01,   4.73986708e-02,   2.62912235e-01],
   [  1.16656423e-01,   4.75735920e-02,   2.72320803e-01],
   [  1.22908126e-01,   4.75360183e-02,   2.81624170e-01],
   [  1.29284984e-01,   4.72930838e-02,   2.90788012e-01],
   [  1.35778450e-01,   4.68563678e-02,   2.99776404e-01],
   [  1.42377819e-01,   4.62422566e-02,   3.08552910e-01],
   [  1.49072957e-01,   4.54676444e-02,   3.17085139e-01],
   [  1.55849711e-01,   4.45588056e-02,   3.25338414e-01],
   [  1.62688939e-01,   4.35542881e-02,   3.33276678e-01],
   [  1.69575148e-01,   4.24893149e-02,   3.40874188e-01],
   [  1.76493202e-01,   4.14017089e-02,   3.48110606e-01],
   [  1.83428775e-01,   4.03288858e-02,   3.54971391e-01],
   [  1.90367453e-01,   3.93088888e-02,   3.61446945e-01],
   [  1.97297425e-01,   3.84001825e-02,   3.67534629e-01],
   [  2.04209298e-01,   3.76322609e-02,   3.73237557e-01],
   [  2.11095463e-01,   3.70296488e-02,   3.78563264e-01],
   [  2.17948648e-01,   3.66146049e-02,   3.83522415e-01],
   [  2.24762908e-01,   3.64049901e-02,   3.88128944e-01],
   [  2.31538148e-01,   3.64052511e-02,   3.92400150e-01],
   [  2.38272961e-01,   3.66209949e-02,   3.96353388e-01],
   [  2.44966911e-01,   3.70545017e-02,   4.00006615e-01],
   [  2.51620354e-01,   3.77052832e-02,   4.03377897e-01],
   [  2.58234265e-01,   3.85706153e-02,   4.06485031e-01],
   [  2.64809649e-01,   3.96468666e-02,   4.09345373e-01],
   [  2.71346664e-01,   4.09215821e-02,   4.11976086e-01],
   [  2.77849829e-01,   4.23528741e-02,   4.14392106e-01],
   [  2.84321318e-01,   4.39325787e-02,   4.16607861e-01],
   [  2.90763373e-01,   4.56437598e-02,   4.18636756e-01],
   [  2.97178251e-01,   4.74700293e-02,   4.20491164e-01],
   [  3.03568182e-01,   4.93958927e-02,   4.22182449e-01],
   [  3.09935342e-01,   5.14069729e-02,   4.23720999e-01],
   [  3.16281835e-01,   5.34901321e-02,   4.25116277e-01],
   [  3.22609671e-01,   5.56335178e-02,   4.26376869e-01],
   [  3.28920763e-01,   5.78265505e-02,   4.27510546e-01],
   [  3.35216916e-01,   6.00598734e-02,   4.28524320e-01],
   [  3.41499828e-01,   6.23252772e-02,   4.29424503e-01],
   [  3.47771086e-01,   6.46156100e-02,   4.30216765e-01],
   [  3.54032169e-01,   6.69246832e-02,   4.30906186e-01],
   [  3.60284449e-01,   6.92471753e-02,   4.31497309e-01],
   [  3.66529195e-01,   7.15785403e-02,   4.31994185e-01],
   [  3.72767575e-01,   7.39149211e-02,   4.32400419e-01],
   [  3.79000659e-01,   7.62530701e-02,   4.32719214e-01],
   [  3.85228383e-01,   7.85914864e-02,   4.32954973e-01],
   [  3.91452659e-01,   8.09267058e-02,   4.33108763e-01],
   [  3.97674379e-01,   8.32568129e-02,   4.33182647e-01],
   [  4.03894278e-01,   8.55803445e-02,   4.33178526e-01],
   [  4.10113015e-01,   8.78961593e-02,   4.33098056e-01],
   [  4.16331169e-01,   9.02033992e-02,   4.32942678e-01],
   [  4.22549249e-01,   9.25014543e-02,   4.32713635e-01],
   [  4.28767696e-01,   9.47899342e-02,   4.32411996e-01],
   [  4.34986885e-01,   9.70686417e-02,   4.32038673e-01],
   [  4.41207124e-01,   9.93375510e-02,   4.31594438e-01],
   [  4.47428382e-01,   1.01597079e-01,   4.31080497e-01],
   [  4.53650614e-01,   1.03847716e-01,   4.30497898e-01],
   [  4.59874623e-01,   1.06089165e-01,   4.29845789e-01],
   [  4.66100494e-01,   1.08321923e-01,   4.29124507e-01],
   [  4.72328255e-01,   1.10546584e-01,   4.28334320e-01],
   [  4.78557889e-01,   1.12763831e-01,   4.27475431e-01],
   [  4.84789325e-01,   1.14974430e-01,   4.26547991e-01],
   [  4.91022448e-01,   1.17179219e-01,   4.25552106e-01],
   [  4.97257069e-01,   1.19379132e-01,   4.24487908e-01],
   [  5.03492698e-01,   1.21575414e-01,   4.23356110e-01],
   [  5.09729541e-01,   1.23768654e-01,   4.22155676e-01],
   [  5.15967304e-01,   1.25959947e-01,   4.20886594e-01],
   [  5.22205646e-01,   1.28150439e-01,   4.19548848e-01],
   [  5.28444192e-01,   1.30341324e-01,   4.18142411e-01],
   [  5.34682523e-01,   1.32533845e-01,   4.16667258e-01],
   [  5.40920186e-01,   1.34729286e-01,   4.15123366e-01],
   [  5.47156706e-01,   1.36928959e-01,   4.13510662e-01],
   [  5.53391649e-01,   1.39134147e-01,   4.11828882e-01],
   [  5.59624442e-01,   1.41346265e-01,   4.10078028e-01],
   [  5.65854477e-01,   1.43566769e-01,   4.08258132e-01],
   [  5.72081108e-01,   1.45797150e-01,   4.06369246e-01],
   [  5.78303656e-01,   1.48038934e-01,   4.04411444e-01],
   [  5.84521407e-01,   1.50293679e-01,   4.02384829e-01],
   [  5.90733615e-01,   1.52562977e-01,   4.00289528e-01],
   [  5.96939751e-01,   1.54848232e-01,   3.98124897e-01],
   [  6.03138930e-01,   1.57151161e-01,   3.95891308e-01],
   [  6.09330184e-01,   1.59473549e-01,   3.93589349e-01],
   [  6.15512627e-01,   1.61817111e-01,   3.91219295e-01],
   [  6.21685340e-01,   1.64183582e-01,   3.88781456e-01],
   [  6.27847374e-01,   1.66574724e-01,   3.86276180e-01],
   [  6.33997746e-01,   1.68992314e-01,   3.83703854e-01],
   [  6.40135447e-01,   1.71438150e-01,   3.81064906e-01],
   [  6.46259648e-01,   1.73913876e-01,   3.78358969e-01],
   [  6.52369348e-01,   1.76421271e-01,   3.75586209e-01],
   [  6.58463166e-01,   1.78962399e-01,   3.72748214e-01],
   [  6.64539964e-01,   1.81539111e-01,   3.69845599e-01],
   [  6.70598572e-01,   1.84153268e-01,   3.66879025e-01],
   [  6.76637795e-01,   1.86806728e-01,   3.63849195e-01],
   [  6.82656407e-01,   1.89501352e-01,   3.60756856e-01],
   [  6.88653158e-01,   1.92238994e-01,   3.57602797e-01],
   [  6.94626769e-01,   1.95021500e-01,   3.54387853e-01],
   [  7.00575937e-01,   1.97850703e-01,   3.51112900e-01],
   [  7.06499709e-01,   2.00728196e-01,   3.47776863e-01],
   [  7.12396345e-01,   2.03656029e-01,   3.44382594e-01],
   [  7.18264447e-01,   2.06635993e-01,   3.40931208e-01],
   [  7.24102613e-01,   2.09669834e-01,   3.37423766e-01],
   [  7.29909422e-01,   2.12759270e-01,   3.33861367e-01],
   [  7.35683432e-01,   2.15905976e-01,   3.30245147e-01],
   [  7.41423185e-01,   2.19111589e-01,   3.26576275e-01],
   [  7.47127207e-01,   2.22377697e-01,   3.22855952e-01],
   [  7.52794009e-01,   2.25705837e-01,   3.19085410e-01],
   [  7.58422090e-01,   2.29097492e-01,   3.15265910e-01],
   [  7.64009940e-01,   2.32554083e-01,   3.11398734e-01],
   [  7.69556038e-01,   2.36076967e-01,   3.07485188e-01],
   [  7.75058888e-01,   2.39667435e-01,   3.03526312e-01],
   [  7.80517023e-01,   2.43326720e-01,   2.99522665e-01],
   [  7.85928794e-01,   2.47055968e-01,   2.95476756e-01],
   [  7.91292674e-01,   2.50856232e-01,   2.91389943e-01],
   [  7.96607144e-01,   2.54728485e-01,   2.87263585e-01],
   [  8.01870689e-01,   2.58673610e-01,   2.83099033e-01],
   [  8.07081807e-01,   2.62692401e-01,   2.78897629e-01],
   [  8.12239008e-01,   2.66785558e-01,   2.74660698e-01],
   [  8.17340818e-01,   2.70953688e-01,   2.70389545e-01],
   [  8.22385784e-01,   2.75197300e-01,   2.66085445e-01],
   [  8.27372474e-01,   2.79516805e-01,   2.61749643e-01],
   [  8.32299481e-01,   2.83912516e-01,   2.57383341e-01],
   [  8.37165425e-01,   2.88384647e-01,   2.52987700e-01],
   [  8.41968959e-01,   2.92933312e-01,   2.48563825e-01],
   [  8.46708768e-01,   2.97558528e-01,   2.44112767e-01],
   [  8.51383572e-01,   3.02260213e-01,   2.39635512e-01],
   [  8.55992130e-01,   3.07038188e-01,   2.35132978e-01],
   [  8.60533241e-01,   3.11892183e-01,   2.30606009e-01],
   [  8.65005747e-01,   3.16821833e-01,   2.26055368e-01],
   [  8.69408534e-01,   3.21826685e-01,   2.21481734e-01],
   [  8.73740530e-01,   3.26906201e-01,   2.16885699e-01],
   [  8.78000715e-01,   3.32059760e-01,   2.12267762e-01],
   [  8.82188112e-01,   3.37286663e-01,   2.07628326e-01],
   [  8.86301795e-01,   3.42586137e-01,   2.02967696e-01],
   [  8.90340885e-01,   3.47957340e-01,   1.98286080e-01],
   [  8.94304553e-01,   3.53399363e-01,   1.93583583e-01],
   [  8.98192017e-01,   3.58911240e-01,   1.88860212e-01],
   [  9.02002544e-01,   3.64491949e-01,   1.84115876e-01],
   [  9.05735448e-01,   3.70140419e-01,   1.79350388e-01],
   [  9.09390090e-01,   3.75855533e-01,   1.74563472e-01],
   [  9.12965874e-01,   3.81636138e-01,   1.69754764e-01],
   [  9.16462251e-01,   3.87481044e-01,   1.64923826e-01],
   [  9.19878710e-01,   3.93389034e-01,   1.60070152e-01],
   [  9.23214783e-01,   3.99358867e-01,   1.55193185e-01],
   [  9.26470039e-01,   4.05389282e-01,   1.50292329e-01],
   [  9.29644083e-01,   4.11479007e-01,   1.45366973e-01],
   [  9.32736555e-01,   4.17626756e-01,   1.40416519e-01],
   [  9.35747126e-01,   4.23831237e-01,   1.35440416e-01],
   [  9.38675494e-01,   4.30091162e-01,   1.30438175e-01],
   [  9.41521384e-01,   4.36405243e-01,   1.25409440e-01],
   [  9.44284543e-01,   4.42772199e-01,   1.20354038e-01],
   [  9.46964741e-01,   4.49190757e-01,   1.15272059e-01],
   [  9.49561766e-01,   4.55659658e-01,   1.10163947e-01],
   [  9.52075421e-01,   4.62177656e-01,   1.05030614e-01],
   [  9.54505523e-01,   4.68743522e-01,   9.98735931e-02],
   [  9.56851903e-01,   4.75356048e-01,   9.46952268e-02],
   [  9.59114397e-01,   4.82014044e-01,   8.94989073e-02],
   [  9.61292850e-01,   4.88716345e-01,   8.42893891e-02],
   [  9.63387110e-01,   4.95461806e-01,   7.90731907e-02],
   [  9.65397031e-01,   5.02249309e-01,   7.38591143e-02],
   [  9.67322465e-01,   5.09077761e-01,   6.86589199e-02],
   [  9.69163264e-01,   5.15946092e-01,   6.34881971e-02],
   [  9.70919277e-01,   5.22853259e-01,   5.83674890e-02],
   [  9.72590351e-01,   5.29798246e-01,   5.33237243e-02],
   [  9.74176327e-01,   5.36780059e-01,   4.83920090e-02],
   [  9.75677038e-01,   5.43797733e-01,   4.36177922e-02],
   [  9.77092313e-01,   5.50850323e-01,   3.90500131e-02],
   [  9.78421971e-01,   5.57936911e-01,   3.49306227e-02],
   [  9.79665824e-01,   5.65056600e-01,   3.14091591e-02],
   [  9.80823673e-01,   5.72208516e-01,   2.85075931e-02],
   [  9.81895311e-01,   5.79391803e-01,   2.62497353e-02],
   [  9.82880522e-01,   5.86605627e-01,   2.46613416e-02],
   [  9.83779081e-01,   5.93849168e-01,   2.37702263e-02],
   [  9.84590755e-01,   6.01121626e-01,   2.36063833e-02],
   [  9.85315301e-01,   6.08422211e-01,   2.42021174e-02],
   [  9.85952471e-01,   6.15750147e-01,   2.55921853e-02],
   [  9.86502013e-01,   6.23104667e-01,   2.78139496e-02],
   [  9.86963670e-01,   6.30485011e-01,   3.09075459e-02],
   [  9.87337182e-01,   6.37890424e-01,   3.49160639e-02],
   [  9.87622296e-01,   6.45320152e-01,   3.98857472e-02],
   [  9.87818759e-01,   6.52773439e-01,   4.55808037e-02],
   [  9.87926330e-01,   6.60249526e-01,   5.17503867e-02],
   [  9.87944783e-01,   6.67747641e-01,   5.83286889e-02],
   [  9.87873910e-01,   6.75267000e-01,   6.52570167e-02],
   [  9.87713535e-01,   6.82806802e-01,   7.24892330e-02],
   [  9.87463516e-01,   6.90366218e-01,   7.99897176e-02],
   [  9.87123759e-01,   6.97944391e-01,   8.77314215e-02],
   [  9.86694229e-01,   7.05540424e-01,   9.56941797e-02],
   [  9.86174970e-01,   7.13153375e-01,   1.03863324e-01],
   [  9.85565739e-01,   7.20782460e-01,   1.12228756e-01],
   [  9.84865203e-01,   7.28427497e-01,   1.20784651e-01],
   [  9.84075129e-01,   7.36086521e-01,   1.29526579e-01],
   [  9.83195992e-01,   7.43758326e-01,   1.38453063e-01],
   [  9.82228463e-01,   7.51441596e-01,   1.47564573e-01],
   [  9.81173457e-01,   7.59134892e-01,   1.56863224e-01],
   [  9.80032178e-01,   7.66836624e-01,   1.66352544e-01],
   [  9.78806183e-01,   7.74545028e-01,   1.76037298e-01],
   [  9.77497453e-01,   7.82258138e-01,   1.85923357e-01],
   [  9.76108474e-01,   7.89973753e-01,   1.96017589e-01],
   [  9.74637842e-01,   7.97691563e-01,   2.06331925e-01],
   [  9.73087939e-01,   8.05409333e-01,   2.16876839e-01],
   [  9.71467822e-01,   8.13121725e-01,   2.27658046e-01],
   [  9.69783146e-01,   8.20825143e-01,   2.38685942e-01],
   [  9.68040817e-01,   8.28515491e-01,   2.49971582e-01],
   [  9.66242589e-01,   8.36190976e-01,   2.61533898e-01],
   [  9.64393924e-01,   8.43848069e-01,   2.73391112e-01],
   [  9.62516656e-01,   8.51476340e-01,   2.85545675e-01],
   [  9.60625545e-01,   8.59068716e-01,   2.98010219e-01],
   [  9.58720088e-01,   8.66624355e-01,   3.10820466e-01],
   [  9.56834075e-01,   8.74128569e-01,   3.23973947e-01],
   [  9.54997177e-01,   8.81568926e-01,   3.37475479e-01],
   [  9.53215092e-01,   8.88942277e-01,   3.51368713e-01],
   [  9.51546225e-01,   8.96225909e-01,   3.65627005e-01],
   [  9.50018481e-01,   9.03409063e-01,   3.80271225e-01],
   [  9.48683391e-01,   9.10472964e-01,   3.95289169e-01],
   [  9.47594362e-01,   9.17399053e-01,   4.10665194e-01],
   [  9.46809163e-01,   9.24168246e-01,   4.26373236e-01],
   [  9.46391536e-01,   9.30760752e-01,   4.42367495e-01],
   [  9.46402951e-01,   9.37158971e-01,   4.58591507e-01],
   [  9.46902568e-01,   9.43347775e-01,   4.74969778e-01],
   [  9.47936825e-01,   9.49317522e-01,   4.91426053e-01],
   [  9.49544830e-01,   9.55062900e-01,   5.07859649e-01],
   [  9.51740304e-01,   9.60586693e-01,   5.24203026e-01],
   [  9.54529281e-01,   9.65895868e-01,   5.40360752e-01],
   [  9.57896053e-01,   9.71003330e-01,   5.56275090e-01],
   [  9.61812020e-01,   9.75924241e-01,   5.71925382e-01],
   [  9.66248822e-01,   9.80678193e-01,   5.87205773e-01],
   [  9.71161622e-01,   9.85282161e-01,   6.02154330e-01],
   [  9.76510983e-01,   9.89753437e-01,   6.16760413e-01],
   [  9.82257307e-01,   9.94108844e-01,   6.31017009e-01], [ 9.88362068e-01, 9.98364143e-01, 6.44924005e-01]]"
```

the tough part is converting the e- format:

```
pyArrayToList[p_String] := 
 ToExpression@
  StringReplace[
   p, {m : NumberString ~~ "e" ~~ exp : NumberString :> 
     m <> " 10^" <> exp, "[" -> "{", "]" -> "}"}]

inferno = With[{x = RGBColor @@@ pyArrayToList@pyarray}, Blend[x, #] &];
BarLegend[{inferno, {0, 1}}]
```

[image]

note per comment by @Kuba this works as well:

```
inferno = With[{x=RGBColor @@@ ImportString[pyarray, "JSON"]},Blend[x, #] &];
```

the `StringReplace` is actually a tad faster, but not so much to make a difference.

Comment: `ImportString[ pyarray, "JSON" ]` this should do too.

Comment: @Kuba, yes it does..thanks

Answer (score 6):

Many months ago, I decided to make "reduced" versions of the popular color gradients from [Matplotlib](https://matplotlib.org/), as well as the [`parula`](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/parula.html) colormap from MATLAB. (I previously blogged about `parula` [here](https://tpfto.wordpress.com/2018/03/05/on-emulating-the-parula-colormap-in-mathematica/).)

These are "reduced" in the sense that unlike the original colormaps that need to keep an array of 256 RGB triplets around, I was able to pare down the list of colors to a smaller portion, while still preserving the features of the color gradient. Since `Blend[]` is fine with handling non-equispaced colors, one can use it with these "reduced" color gradients.

I posted these colormaps [here](https://gist.github.com/tpfto/fea9b56a4f99b5a47d32ba03ab3224b8) and [here](https://pastebin.com/qcyE3vzF). (**Update**: "cividis", a color-blind-friendly variation of "viridis" presented in [this paper](https://doi.org/10.1371/journal.pone.0199239), is now also implemented.)

To load these gradients into *Mathematica*, evaluate e.g.

```
Get["https://pastebin.com/raw/qcyE3vzF"]
```

To use the color gradients, just evaluate `makeBlend[colorName]`; e.g.

```
ContourPlot[Sin[x + Cos[y]] Cos[Sin[x] + y], {x, -3 π, 3 π}, {y, -3 π, 3 π}, 
            ColorFunction -> makeBlend["Parula"], PlotPoints -> 75]
```

[image: contour plot colored with parula]

---

Here is how the color gradients look, as well as the result of converting them to grayscale with `ColorConvert[]`, and applying color blindness effects to them with `ImageEffect[]`:

[image: reduced gradients]

I will continue this discussion with a specific example, the "viridis" color gradient. We can use [Kovesi's test image](https://peterkovesi.com/projects/colourmaps/colourmaptestimage.html) to see how "viridis" performs after being transformed. First, generate the test image:

```
kovesi = Block[{nc = 64 + 1/2, pixc = 8, a = 1/20, w, h},
               w = pixc nc + 1; h = Round[(w - 1)/4];
               Image[N[Join[Outer[Times, (Range[h, 1, -1]/(h - 1))^2,
                                  -a Cos[2 π Range[0, w - 1]/pixc]] + 
                            ConstantArray[Subdivide[a, 1 - a, w - 1], h], 
                            ConstantArray[Subdivide[w - 1], Round[h/4]]]]]]
```

[image: Kovesi's test image]

We can use `Colorize[]` to test "viridis":

```
img = Colorize[kovesi, ColorFunction -> makeBlend["Viridis"]]
```

[image: Kovesi image, viridis colormap]

Convert to grayscale:

```
ColorConvert[img, GrayLevel]
```

[image: Kovesi image, grayscale conversion]

How a protanopic person might see the image:

```
ImageEffect[img, {"ColorBlindness", "Protanopia"}]
```

[image: Kovesi image, protanopic coloration]

Answer (score 4):

Basically an update on what Jason B. has already but with the addition of some stuff for making pretty `Format` forms / faking a proper `ColorDataFunction`:

```
getPyArray[url_] :=
 ToExpression@StringReplace[
   "[" <>
    Riffle[
     StringCases[
      Import[URL[url], "Text"],
      Whitespace ~~ "[" ~~
       Whitespace ~~ 
       NumberString ~~ (("e" ~~ NumberString) | "") ~~ "," ~~
       
       Whitespace ~~ NumberString ~~ (("e" ~~ NumberString) | "") ~~ "," ~~
  
            Whitespace ~~ NumberString ~~ (("e" ~~ NumberString) | "") ~~ "]"
      ],
     ","
     ] <> "]",
   {
    "e" -> "*^",
    "[" -> "{",
    "]" -> "}"
    }]

Unprotect[ColorDataFunction];
(* hacked this from the ColorDataFunction FormatValues and Subvalues *)

MakeBoxes[
   colf : ColorDataFunction[ scheme_, "Matplotlib",  range_, cf_Function],  
   fmt_
   ] :=
  With[{ thumbBoxes = LinearGradientImage[cf, {100, 15}], 
    rangeBoxes = MakeBoxes[ range, fmt]},
   BoxForm`ArrangeSummaryBox[
    ColorDataFunction,
    colf,
    None,
    {
     BoxForm`MakeSummaryItem[{"Name:", scheme}, fmt],
      BoxForm`MakeSummaryItem[{"Gradient:", thumbBoxes}, fmt]
     },
    {
      BoxForm`MakeSummaryItem[{"Domain:", range}, fmt],
     BoxForm`MakeSummaryItem[{"Class:", "Matplotlib"}, fmt]
     },
    fmt
    ]
   ];
ColorDataFunction[ scheme_, "Matplotlib", range_, f_][ x_] := Quiet[ f[ x]]
Protect[ColorDataFunction];
$MPLColorMaps =
  MapThread[
    # ->
      With[{d = RGBColor @@@ getPyArray[#2]},
       ColorDataFunction[#, "Matplotlib", {0, 1}, Blend[d, #] &]
       ] &,
    {
     {"Magma", "Inferno", "Plasma", "Viridis", "EricsRdBuGnYl", 
      "EricsRdBuGnYl2", "EricsPuBuGnYl", "FakeParula", "JoesBluGrnPnk2"},
     {"https://raw.githubusercontent.com/BIDS/colormap/master/option_a.py", 
      "https://raw.githubusercontent.com/BIDS/colormap/master/option_b.py", 
      "https://raw.githubusercontent.com/BIDS/colormap/master/option_c.py", 
      "https://raw.githubusercontent.com/BIDS/colormap/master/option_d.py", 
      "https://github.com/BIDS/colormap/raw/master/erics-RdBuGnYl_r.py", 
      "https://github.com/BIDS/colormap/raw/master/erics-RdBuGnYl_r_v2.py", 
      "https://github.com/BIDS/colormap/raw/master/erics_PuBuGnYl_r.py", 
      "https://github.com/BIDS/colormap/raw/master/fake_parula.py", 
      "https://github.com/BIDS/colormap/raw/master/joes-blu_grn_pnk2.py"}
     }
    ] // Association;
```

Here's what they look like

[image]