# PlotStyle for four surfaces

Tags: plotting

How can I choose the PlotStyle such that the four surfaces are visible (at least to some extent) in the following plot

```
 Plot3D[{Sin[0.5 x y], Cos[0.5 x y], Sin[x y], Cos[x y]}, {x, 0, 
  2 \[Pi]}, {y, 0, 2 \[Pi]}]
```

Edit: To be specific, I want these plots should look different from each other when one takes a black and white printout.

Comment: What exactly are you asking? All surfaces are visible when I run your command.

Comment: Maybe add some transparency? `PlotStyle -> Opacity[.4]`

Comment: @Natas, I mean when someone takes a black n white printout of this plot, he/she should be able to make the distinction in the surfaces to some extent.

Answer (score 6):

```
(* 12.1 *)
styles = {{Gray}, {HalftoneShading[], 
    White}, {HatchShading[.5], White}, {StippleShading[.3], White}};
Plot3D[{Sin[0.5 x y], Cos[0.5 x y], Sin[x y], Cos[x y]}, {x, 0, 
  2 π}, {y, 0, 2 π}, PlotStyle -> styles, Mesh -> None, 
 Lighting -> "Accent", PlotPoints -> 50]
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

From the comments you seem to want a grayscale visible colorscheme. There are plenty of them, in Mathematica, check the documentation to `ColorData`.
Also check the viridis colormap in mathematica:
[Colormaps for linear visual perception AND grayscale printing](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/127306/colormaps-for-linear-visual-perception-and-grayscale-printing)

With the colorscheme "AvocadoColors" you can get something like this:

```
color = ColorData["AvocadoColors"][#] & /@ Subdivide[0.2, 1, 3];
p = Plot3D[{Sin[0.5 x y], Cos[0.5 x y], Sin[x y], Cos[x y]}, {x, 0, 
   2 \[Pi]}, {y, 0, 2 \[Pi]}, PlotStyle -> color]
ColorConvert[p, "Grayscale"]
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks, @Mr Puh, it would be nice if one can have these curves with different mesh styles, so that in black-n-white mode, one can actually differentiate these surfaces easily. Something like this: one surface with mesh lines, one with mesh dashed lines, one with mesh dotted lines, and  one without mesh.

Comment: Use the option `MeshStyle` of Plot3D.